# CSS custom checkboxes

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a page with 30 Checkboxes on it. Those are for seat reservation. 
Now i tried to style them.

```css
.seatlayout{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: table;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 6% 2% 0% 2%;
  border-radius: 5%;
}
.seat{
  position: relative;
  width: 22%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
[class*='seatcont'],
.seatdis{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

[class^="seatcon"] label,
.seatdis label{
  background-color: #f1f2ed;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

[class^="seatcon"] input[type="checkbox"] ,
.seatdis input[type="checkbox"] {
  z-index:10

}

[class^="seatcon"] input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label
{
  background-color: #66bb6a;
}

.seatdis input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  background-color: grey;
  pointer-events: none
}

[class^="seatcon"] input[type="checkbox"]:checked +  
label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="seatlayout">
 <div class="seat">
    <div class="seatcont1">
       <input type="checkbox id="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox" id="lab1">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="seat">
    <div class="seatcont2">
       <input type="checkbox id="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox" id="lab2">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="seat">
    <div class="seatcont3">
       <input type="checkbox id="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox" id="lab3">
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

> **Problem** 
>   No matter on which seat i click on, it always checkes the first one. I tried several approaches adding unique classes and id's while working with wildcards. Any help would be highly apprieciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same id for every checkbox. You should use a unique id for each one.

Answer (score 1):

You've put the same id on all of your checkboxes. You need to give them all a different id.
Additionally, you are missing an ending quote on all of your checkboxes after the type.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox" id="lab1">

....

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
<label for="checkbox2" id="lab1">
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! The missing ending quote was a copy paste issue =S

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong.
The `label` element is never closed. The `label` element doesn't need an `id` it's the `for` attribute that needs to match the id of the `input`. Second the `input` of the checkboxes is never closed by an `"`. Third the `id` always needs to be unique, it's a unique [**id**entifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). So every input needs to have their own unique id.

```css
.seatlayout{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: table;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 6% 2% 0% 2%;
  border-radius: 5%;
}
.seat{
  position: relative;
  width: 22%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
[class*='seatcont'],
.seatdis{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

[class^="seatcon"] label,
.seatdis label{
  background-color: #f1f2ed;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

[class^="seatcon"] input[type="checkbox"] ,
.seatdis input[type="checkbox"] {
  z-index:10

}

[class^="seatcon"] input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label
{
  background-color: #66bb6a;
}

.seatdis input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  background-color: grey;
  pointer-events: none
}

[class^="seatcon"] input[type="checkbox"]:checked +  
label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="seatlayout">
 <div class="seat">
    <div class="seatcont1">
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
       <label for="checkbox1"> 1</label>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="seat">
    <div class="seatcont2">
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
       <label for="checkbox2"> 2</label>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="seat">
    <div class="seatcont3">
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
       <label for="checkbox3"> 3</label>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Got it working =)